# Data not displaying in bootstrap table using flask

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, python-2.7, flask, jinja2, bootstrap-modal

Hello I am in need of a little help please, I have no data showing up in a table.
I have data being posted from a bootstrap modal form to the sqlite3 database.

any help would be great.

Here is the view

```
    @dashboard.route('/stream/products', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
    @login_required
    def products():
        product = Product()
        form = ProductForm(product=product)
        if current_user.can(Permission.WRITE_PRODUCTS) and \
            form.validate_on_submit():
            filename = secure_filename(form.image.data.filename)
            form.image.data.save('./app/static/uploads/' + filename)
            product.name=form.name.data
            product.description=form.description.data
            product.part=form.part.data
            product.price=form.price.data
            product.manager=current_user._get_current_object()
            db.session.add(product)
           flash('The product has been updated.')
           return redirect(url_for('.products',name=product.name))
           form.name.data=product.name
           form.description.data=product.description
           form.part.data=product.part
           form.price.data=product.price
           products = Product.query.order_by(Product.name.desc()).all()
       else:
           filename = None
        return render_template('dashboard/content/products.html',form=form,  filename=filename, product=product )
```

here is the html I can not seem to find what the missing link is.

```
    <tbody>
    {% for product in products %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
    <td colspan="1">{{ product.image(class="img-responsive" ) }}</td>
    <td colspan="3">{{ product.name }}</td>
    <td colspan="1">{{ product.part }}</td>
    <td colspan="2">{{ product.price }}</td>
    <td colspan="1"><button type="button">Edit</button></td>
    <td colspan="1"><button type="button" >Delete</button></td>
    <td colspan="1"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

The model is this.

```
     class Product(db.Model):
         __tablename__ = 'products'
         id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
         name = db.Column(db.String(55))
         description = db.Column(db.Text)
         part = db.Column(db.String(55))
         price = db.Column(db.Integer)
         manager_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `db.session.commit()` after `db.session.add(product)`

commit() flushes pending changes and commit the current transaction.

If you fail to call that then your changes are rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

The code after the line:
   `return redirect(url_for('.products',name=product.name))` 
is dead. Return leaves the current function, so the the code in the lines following that until the `else:` is never executed, so the data will not show up in your form.